# Show specific menu item from wp_nav_menu based on id

Tags: wordpress, menu

I have a wp_nav_menu "Main Menu" such as the following:

- Top Level (#menu-item-1)

  - Sub Item
  - Sub Item
- Top Level (#menu-item-2)

  - Sub Item
- Top Level (#menu-item-3)

  - Sub Item A
  - Sub Item B
  - Sub Item C

Then in my template I want to be able to echo wp_nav_menu Main Menu sub items for say top level with id of menu-item-3.

So something like this: (but that would actually work of course)

```
wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Main Menu' 'menu-item-id' => '3' ));
```

And that would return:

```
<ul>
<li>Sub Item A</li>
<li>Sub Item B</li>
<li>Sub Item C</li>
</ul>
```

If it matters this is so I can show the sub items as side menu interior based on which main menu item section your in dynamically. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

While looking for this myself I came across:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2802/display-a-portion-branch-of-the-menu-tree-using-wp-nav-menu/2809#2809

The trick is to add a custom Walker.